# Как отключить бота дискорд на python?

Tags: python, api, бот, discord

У меня есть код.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

settings = {
    'token': '',
    'bot': 'NutrixBot',
    'id': ,
    'prefix': '$'
}
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix']) 



@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        await ctx.reply("печатать")


bot.run("token") # Обращаемся к словарю settings с ключом token, для получения токена
```

и этот бот просто без перерывно спамит! Я даже когда удалял и запускал его снова, закрывал IDE, но он всё равно печатает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: [Бот спамит при вызове `on_message`](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/problems/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%20on_message.md)

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в cmdшник бота и ctrl + c